# What is the purpose of the 'runIDE' Gradle task in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I execute the 'runIDE' task inside of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.1.3, it opens IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (which is not even installed on my system...yet still opens somehow) to the starting page. Nothing gets displayed, the project is not re-opened in the Community Edition...it just sits there.

Comment: It's used for plug-in development, see https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin.

Comment: @CrazyCoder TY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`runIDE` Gradle task is provided by [gradle-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) and is used when developing IntelliJ IDEA plug-ins to start a new instance from the IDE to test the plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

It runs the task `prepareSandbox` that downloads a test IDE ready for use.
Then you have to open a project or create a new one on the sandbox to test your plugin.
For example, if you are coding a syntax highlighter for a new language, create a project and create a file with your language extension and test the highlighting.